# Assign Time,date and city To All P Tags with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three div tags with class `art_footer`.

I am trying to print date, time and city with JavaScript but it's giving the result to only one frame.

So how can I do same with multiple divs in javascript?

```js
var dd = today.getDate();
var today = new Date();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

var currentdate = new Date();

if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd
}

if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm
}

var today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;

var datetime = "" + currentdate.getHours() + ":" +
    currentdate.getMinutes();

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mydate");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].innerHtml = today;
}

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mytime");
var j;
for (j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
    x[j].innerHtml = datetime;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" />

<div class="art_footer">
    <p id="mydate">&nbsp <span class="mydate"></span></p>
    <p id="mytime">&nbsp &nbsp <span class="mytime"></span></p>
    <p class="fa fa-map-marker">&nbsp Hyderabad<span class="mycity"></span>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="art_footer">
    <p id="mydate">&nbsp <span class="mydate"></span></p>
    <p id="mytime">&nbsp &nbsp <span class="mytime"></span></p>
    <p class="fa fa-map-marker">&nbsp Hyderabad<span class="mycity"></span>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="art_footer">
    <p id="mydate">&nbsp <span class="mydate"></span></p>
    <p id="mytime">&nbsp &nbsp <span class="mytime"></span></p>
    <p class="fa fa-map-marker">&nbsp Hyderabad<span class="mycity"></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: id attributes have to have unique values. You're using the id "mytime" for more than one element.

Comment: yes, that's what I am trying to ask how can I populate results same id.

Comment: Used `getElementsByClassName` in javascript

Comment: I am trying to do that but value of variable is not assigning

Comment: The answer is to not use the same id value. Give the elements a *class* instead.

Comment: "java script" is not JavaScript

Comment: thank for a change !!

Answer (score 0):

You try this

Set `class="mydate"` for span

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mydate");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) 
{
    x[i].innerHTML=today;
}
```

Do same for all span

Comment: But how can I assign a value to it like( .innerhtml=value ;) to it.

Comment: You see in for loop you can assign value `x[i].innerHTML=today;`

Comment: I have edited my post using ur solution but not working, can you say where I am doing wrong.

Comment: You can also change `<span class="mydate">`